# How can you have a column equal ALL items in a list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, PC and SC. In SC, I have a list of 3 colors (Red, Blue, Green). In PC, I have 2 columns Name and Color, and goes as follows:

```
Name      Color
Tom       Red
Tom       Blue
Tom       Green
Mike      Red
Mike      Blue
James     Green
Joe       Red
Joe       Blue
Joe       Green
James     Brown
```

I need to return the names from PC where the Color column includes ALL the colors from SC. How can this be accomplished?

This is what I was trying, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PC.Name
FROM PC
INNER JOIN SC ON PC.ColorCode = SC.ColorCode
WHERE PC.ColorCode IN (SELECT ColorCode FROM SC);
```

Please help.

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting. First time posting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [**HAVING**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180199.aspx) clause to filter the groups

```
select name from pc 
group by Name
having count(distinct color) = (SELECT count(distinct color) FROM SC)
```

Comment: Note that OP's sample data includes colors in the name color table that aren't in the color only table. So you can match on count without matching on colors. I believe adding OP's where clause to your solution will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `exists`:

```
select distinct name
from pc p1
where not exists(select * from sc 
                 where colorcode not in(select color from pc p2
                                        where p1.name = p2.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT P.NAME
FROM PC P
LEFT JOIN SC S ON P.COLOR=S.COLOR
WHERE S.COLOR IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY P.NAME
```